# homepage images are not showing in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've uploaded all `prestashop files` to `web server`, there `homepage images` are not displaying only broken image symbol is showing. `product page` images and `cms page` images are showing. only homepage `images` are not showing.

i run the same files in my `localhost` there i can see all the images in the homepage.

problem occure only when i run `prestashop` files through `webserver`.

what difference in my localhost server and webserver....?
why images are not displaying in homepage only...?

please give me solution  for my problem

Comment: Check the images path using inspect element in localhost and in webserver. Check where it breaks.

Comment: i checked it already path is correct if i upload new image also same problem it's not showing actual image, only showing broken image.

Comment: send the localhost path of any image, and from server

Comment: have you used relative or absolute path?

Comment: relative path. in prestashop when we upload images it stores in the local directory and display's image from the local directory.

Comment: Have you a link of your webserver?

Comment: Can you go to _Settings_ >> _SEO & URL's_ in admin panel, once there, save the settings (yes without changing anyhting). Then reload the homepage.